# Load Modules in Wing IDE

Tags: python, wing-ide

I am new to Python and am having trouble loading numpy in Wing IDE. I can load the module and use it fine in the command line but not in Wing IDE. Below is what I am seeing:

**code:**

import numpy as np

a=np.arange(15)

**result:**

[evaluate numpy.py]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users[my name]\Documents\Python\practice\numpy.py", line 2, in 0
builtins.NameError: name 'arange' is not defined

I have also tried to use the help() command:

**code:**

help(np)

**result:**

Help on module numpy:

NAME
    numpy

FILE
    c:\users[my name]\documents\python\practice\numpy.py

Answer (score 1):

It is probably due to your code being in a file named numpy.py   If you do this then 'import numpy' may import your module and not numpy.  This depends on what's on the Python Path and possibly current directory, which probably explains why it works outside of Wing.

Comment: Changing the file name worked! Thank you!

Other than carefully naming files, do you have ideas on how to prevent this from happening in the future? This is an issue even when using IDLE.

Right now, I have C:\Python34 as one of the paths in system variables. I am considering removing it.